# First item in RecyclerView does not go under status bar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-statusbar

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.skillberg.weather.ui.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/weather_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

I want the first item in RecyclerView to be displayed under the status bar (like toolbar), but it's not being displayed there:

[image]

However, RecyclerView itself draws under status bar, but it seems that there is some top padding which height = status bar height:

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: remove  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"  from RecyclerView

Comment: @VinayakB if I remove it, it positions below the status bar: https://i.imgur.com/RFySVcx.jpg

Comment: why don't you add <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>  in your style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand your `AppTheme` with `windowTranslucentStatus` e.g.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        // other stuff
</style>
```

This will allow the `StatusBar` to be transparent. You don't need to use `android:fitsSystemWindows`.

Comment: One more question: is there a way to remove grey tint: https://i.imgur.com/UuBi251.png ? I've tried to google, but nothing helped.

Comment: which gray tint?

Comment: @arts777 There are different answers to that topic and none of them is working reliably. You might want to open a new question for that.

Answer (score 2):

In you CoordinatorLayout  change this `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to `false`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the behavior that works in pair with the CoordinatorLayout.
Simply add it to your RecyclerView as follow :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/weather_rv"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
```

Comment: Nothing changed :(